# creating and theming register form in drupal 7

Tags: theming, users

There are many links in websites that talk about this question, but I'm really bewildered how to do it, I've tested many solutions but I failed.

this is my code to add register form into a page

```
<?php
    if(user_is_anonymous()) {  
    $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
    print drupal_render($form);
    }
?>
```

it is all I know of register form !
it prints all the fields of registered users. I also added other fields like mobile, phone and ... from admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

what is the most straightforward solution to theme the form? text fields and ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one

To implement `hook_form_alter()` in a module and set the form's #theme property:

```
    function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      $form['#theme'] = 'user_register';
    }
```

and add this code to template.php

```
    function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
      return array(
        'user_register' => array(
          'render element' => 'form',
          'template' => 'templates/user-register',
        ),
      );
    }

function mytheme_preprocess_user_register(&$variables) {
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($variables['form']);
}
```

Also, create a user-register.tpl.php in

> sites/all/modules/YOUR_module/templates/user-register.tpl.php

to add the 'markup' for the desired output and

```
<?php echo $rendered; ?>
```

to print the form.

For more information, follow this https://www.drupal.org/node/1211520

Hope, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Open template.php of your theme

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

 $hooks['form_id_of_form'] = array(
    'template' => 'path_to_tpl_file',
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

Also you can try

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'form_id_of_form') {
    $form['#theme'] = 'path_to_tpl_file';
  }
}
```

OR

Take a look at the #theme key in the Form API Reference. Take a look at the code for theme_form() for the default implementation.

Comment: Links are not considered as answers here. Please update your answer with details

Comment: Updated the answer.